# What may be preventing in-place editing in my rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I have a rails 4 app in which i want to use Best in Place or Rest in Place or any gem to provide in-place editing.

I've tried with those two. With both, I set the "name" attribute of a User to be editable in place.

When I visit the show page of a user, I click the name and the input field appears. But when submitted, it won't update the record.

Logs:

```
Processing by UsersController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"lkj"}, "authenticity_token"=>"TOz1cbnLc5KrX5JLZl0hiOsf7ZvwXhp6lD2qUIfH+og=", "id"=>"7"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '62f0af062cc8544a31bfe5a02ef00bf34d449959' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "7"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('juan@juan.com') AND "users"."id" != 7) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 41ms
```

Can it be that the message being sent is a PUT and not PATCH?

My Update action in Users controller:

```
def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Perfil actualizado"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what's your routes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

to the following:

```
if @user.update_attributes!(user_params)
```

You will have a more detailed message of the error.

if this does not work, try `Rails.logger.debug(user_params)` to view your params hash in the logs.

summary:

```
def update
    if @user.update_attributes!(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Perfil actualizado"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Debug accordingly!

Comment: thanks jquadrin, with the more detailed message of the error i just realized user_params was also sending a 'password' param with null value which was not passing validation. thanks and regards.